# CSS drop-up menu with second row on top-left

Tags: css, menu

I have menu position on botoom of the page.
And I need to have three level menu, when each level is in row and located to the left.

**My CSS Code:**

```css
.primary-navigation {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    top: 80px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.primary-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.primary-navigation ul > li,
.primary-navigation ul > li > ul > li,
 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.primary-navigation ul ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
.primary-navigation li > ul {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: -50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.primary-navigation li:hover > ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 600px;

}

.primary-navigation li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.primary-navigation li ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.primary-navigation a {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 9px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="primary-navigation">
<ul>
  <li>Ahoj</li>
  <li>Test A
    <ul>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 2
        <ul>
      <li>Test A</li>
      <li>Test B</li>
      <li>Test C</li>
    </ul></li>
      <li>Test 3</li>
    </ul></li>
  <li>Test B
    <ul>
      <li>Test 4</li>
      <li>Test 5</li>
      <li>Test 6</li>
    </ul></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I know, that there is a problem in  **li > ul** part, when is

```
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: -50%;
```

I know, that "left" give me a horizontal position.

The problem is, how to get this second row to the left and make it wide full length

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, you have to delete the `position: relative` out of your children `<li>` elements, because this is the reason the children of those will align absolute to it's parent (`<li>` and not the `<nav>` itself.) Further, you've to do a little trick with the border, because it affects the absolute positioning. So here I use `box-shadow` on the left side of your elements to achieve the same effect without a border. `border-bottom` is not needed, because you stack the elements anyway.

**CSS for border "trick"**

```
border-right: 2px solid red;
border-top: 2px solid red;
box-shadow: inset 2px 0 0 red //imitates a border-left
```

**SNIPPET**

```css
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}
.primary-navigation {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    top: 80px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
}
.primary-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.primary-navigation ul > li,
.primary-navigation ul > li > ul > li,
 {
  float: left;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.primary-navigation ul ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
.primary-navigation li > ul {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 0 0 red
}
.primary-navigation li:hover > ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 600px;

}

.primary-navigation li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.primary-navigation li ul li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.primary-navigation a {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 9px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="primary-navigation">
<ul>
  <li>Ahoj</li>
  <li>Test A
    <ul>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 2
        <ul>
      <li>Test A</li>
      <li>Test B</li>
      <li>Test C</li>
    </ul></li>
      <li>Test 3</li>
    </ul></li>
  <li>Test B
    <ul>
      <li>Test 4</li>
      <li>Test 5</li>
      <li>Test 6</li>
    </ul></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.